# How can I get unpublished drafts in my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, draft

I'm building a widget where I want to list all unpublished drafts (made by users without access to publish live changes), but I can't figure out how to get them.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do with them you can request them using [craft.entries](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) but you'll probably need to change the **status** to **pending**.

If this doesn't work you'll need to fetch them through a custom controller/service that goes in and fetches the [entry model](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel) and returns a list that fit you criteria.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Drafts store rows in the `craft_entrydrafts` table, relating to an entry, providing some context (author, date, notes), and serializing all the pending content into a data column. Craft normally gets drafts only as they relate to a specific entry, so you'll need to provide your own method of retrieving them all.

The EntryRevisionsService class has a method called getDraftsByEntryId(), which can be modified slightly to return all those draft records rather than ones limited specifically to a given entry:

```
public function getEntryDrafts($localeId = null)
{
    if (!$localeId)
    {
        $localeId = craft()->i18n->getPrimarySiteLocale();
    }

    $drafts = array();

    $results = craft()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('entrydrafts')
        ->where(array('locale = :locale'), array(':locale' => $localeId))
        ->order('dateUpdated desc')
        ->queryAll();

    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
        $result['data'] = JsonHelper::decode($result['data']);

        // Don't initialize the content
        unset($result['data']['fields']);

        $drafts[] = EntryDraftModel::populateModel($result);
    }

    return $drafts;
}
```

Each result will be an EntryDraftModel, so use the `draftId` parameter if you'd like to link directly to that draft as you'd normally see it in the control panel. In a Twig template, for example, that'd look like `{{ draft.cpEditUrl ~ "/drafts/" ~ draft.draftId }}`.